# How OSM routing can be replaced with Mapbox routing in leaflet js

Tags: routes, leaflet, mapbox, openstreetmap

We are facing some issues with routing in OSM maps. Sometimes it loads fine, sometimes 429 error code and sometimes 400 error code.

Kindly suggest any alternatives (in Mapbox) for the below code.

```
var map = L.map('map');
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', { attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors' }).addTo(map);
L.Routing.control({
waypoints: [
    L.latLng(15.0991865,98.9801498),
    L.latLng(54.0810359,98.9867198)
],
routeWhileDragging: true}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: For mapbox routing you’d need an account and a paid subscription.

Comment: Please provide more details. If you are using leaflet routing engine (you didn't explained anything) then you have the choice between many providers: https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine

Comment: Your code just tells us which *tile* server your are using but not which *routing* service.